# What is a term to describe when a percentage of the amount of money paid is taken away from the goods given?

Tags: savings, credit, money-transfer

I have a system, where a 2% "charge" (for want of a better term) applies to all transactions. Users can pay $100, and then they will top up for 98% of that amount (top up for $98).

I was thinking of the term surcharge, but that would be for where the user pays $102, for example, to top up for $100 of goods (2% surcharge).

Is there a term for when the value of the money given by the user is decreased by a percentage?

Comment: inclusive of charge.

Comment: @Dheer Would a correct description be "a 2% inclusive of service charge"?

Comment: Yes that sounds right. Or "inclusive/including of 2% service charge". Generally inclusive is used to indicate as such. You could also try "a 2% deductible towards service charge would apply"

Comment: @Dheer Thanks for that! Perhaps you could post that as an answer, and this question would be answered.

Comment: This sounds like vigorish: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigorish

Comment: What country is this in?  Some countries have legal terms for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be"inclusive/ including 2% service charge" or "2% deductible towards service charge would apply"

Answer (score 1):

It may not apply for your situation, but if you were running a mutual fund, you could use the term "front-end load".